# Apple iOS Swift5 BLE - How to send 1 byte to a characteristic (write function expects Data type, but one byte is "UInt8" type)

Tags: ios, swift, types, integer, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing code that will write data types of Floats, and 8,16,32 bit ints to an existing BLE GATT peripheral. The peripheral characteristics are constructed for those specific sizes. For Floats and 32 bit Ints, creating the Data type tends to create extraneous 0s in the buffer and makes it a 5 byte object, which my peripheral rejects. So I slice it as so:

```
let int32Value = Int32(fieldValue)
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: int32Value) { Data($0) }
let data_slice = data[0...3]
peripheral.writeValue(data_slice, for: characteristic, type: writeType)
```

For 16 bit Ints, I just slice it differently:

```
let int16Value = Int16(fieldValue)
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: int16Value) { Data($0) }
let data_slice = data[0...1]
peripheral.writeValue(data_slice, for: characteristic, type: writeType)
```

All of this works, and I can see the data has been set on the device. But with 8 bit Ints, I try:

```
let int8Value = Int8(fieldValue)
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: int8Value) { Data($0) }
let data_slice = data[0]
peripheral.writeValue(data_slice, for: characteristic, type: writeType)
```

And I get a compile time error - the `writeValue` method requires a `Data` type for the first argument, but from the code above, it interprets `data_slice` as a `Bytes` object and won't compile. If I don't do the "data_slice" operation, then `data` is 2 bytes in length with the way I'm creating it here, and gets rejected by my peripheral. I get the "Incorrect characteristic data length" error.

I seem to be in a Catch-22. The system level `writeValue` function I need to use to send BLE peripheral values doesn't allow a single 8 bit Int as an argument. But the characteristic on my peripheral won't accept anything but that. Sending a single 8 bit Int has worked for me on other platforms such as Android. What do you do in a situation like this?

Images showing the Int8 and Int32 cases:

[image: Int8 case]

[image: Int32 case]

Comment: "then data is 2 bytes in length with the way I'm creating it here" This doesn't make any sense considering that Int8 is a single byte.

Comment: Btw you are not slicing anything. Your data_slice is exactly the same size as your data object

Comment: @LeoDabus, check the edits, I added images showing what I see. Let me know what could be wrong then.

Comment: The issue is that your Int is optional. Thats why you are getting an extra byte. All you need is to unwrap your optional before converting it to Data

Comment: @LeoDabus, oof that's exactly right, and that fixed it. Many thanks! If you want to write a solution I'll give you the answer, or I can just delete this question if it's a silly error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue there is that your `Int8` is an optional. Thats why you are getting an extra byte. All you need is to unwrap your optional before converting it to Data.